# Show WordPress admin bar on frontend for specific user roles

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

I use the code snippet below, because the WP admin bar wasn't showing in the frontend for all user roles besides the admin. But the admin bar is now visible for all users and I only want it to be visible for the two user roles 'shop_manager' and 'editor'. What should the code snippet look like then?

```
function admin_bar(){

  if(is_user_logged_in()){
         add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' , 1000 );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'admin_bar' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
function admin_bar(){
  if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( in_array( 'shop_manager', (array) $user->roles ) || in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
            add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' , 1000 );
        }else{
            add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' , 1000 );
        }

    }
}
add_action('init', 'admin_bar' );
```